# CentOS Service startup with custom parameters (chkconfig)

Tags: centos, sphinx, daemon, startup, runlevel

CentOS uses the chkconfig command to add services to to the startup routine, but how do I add a service and pass parameters to that service?

To be more precise, I'm setting up the Sphinx search engine on a CentoOS 6.5 server and the documentation wants me to do this:

```
chkconfig searchd on
```

But this would fail because my config file is in a non-standard location (I'll eventually have multiple searchd daemons running for multiple websites to use). What I need to do is add this to my startup routine:

```
searchd --config /etc/sphinx/website1/sphinx.conf
searchd --config /etc/sphinx/website2/sphinx.conf
searchd --config /etc/sphinx/website3/sphinx.conf
```

Does this make sense?

Cheers.

Comment: Why do you need multiple instances? One instance can serve many indexes.

Comment: Our server hosts a variety of websites and web based applications for clients of all sizes, and we're wanting to use Sphinx to speed up some of these services and potentially for future developments, so it makes sense to run individual search daemons for each, allowing us to optimise them all individually (different resource assignments, max_matches variables, log files, etc). It also means we can name the indexes the same as the database tables even though multiple sites share the same naming conventions, and we can run cron scripts to rotate indexes on a more controlled schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more proper way to do this, but I ended up just adding the above to my /etc/rc.local file.

Comment: I think a slightly more proper way would be to create duplicates of /etc/init.d/searchd - each one setup with the differnt config files. AFAIK, that is the file that chkconfig manipupates symlinks to.